# minify the website at certain width with css

Tags: html, css

So I have a web application that is not really meant for mobile but in case someone wants to access the app with mobile I'd like to minify the website like this:

from this:

[image: img1]

to this:

[image: img2]

so the user can zoom in on mobile.

How could i do something like this?

Comment: A quick and dirty fix is to leave out the `<meta name="viewport">` tag in your html, then everything will just shrink to fit the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add below tag inside your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1,minimum-scale=0.1">
```

(you can adjust "0.1" value to get best performance)